# Creating a PDF from microsoft access database

Tags: c#, javascript, asp-classic

I would like to create a PDF from the data i have in a microsoft access database. Can someone please tell me what I should use to make this happen? Any tips and steps are appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

One way of doing it is creating a report (you can use CrystalReports) against your AccessDB data, and then exporting that report to PDF.

Other way of doing it is creating a little program in C# and generate a PDF using an Open Source PDF generator like [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/), [PDFCreator](http://www.gotdotnet.com/Community/UserSamples/Details.aspx?SampleGuid=5588085e-3d0b-4db8-8a88-603ef212d0db) or [Report.NET](http://report.sourceforge.net/). There are also a lot of commercial libraries available.

Other way of doing it is creating a little Java program and generate PDF using [iText](http://itextpdf.com/).

Other way of doing it is creating a little *insert your favorite programming language here* and generate a PDF using a suitable library for it.

Answer (score 1):

try this old link I have used this and it produces PDF direcly fron access full credits to Mr Lebans just follow his clear instructions

http://www.lebans.com/reporttopdf.htm

Comment: It bears mentioning that Lebans makes it abundantly clear on the front page of that site that he (as of 2009) no longer will support the product. In case of pdf, which is a changing format, this is relevant.